# VK Oauth: Authenticating user, giving error

Tags: vk

I created an application in VK. But, when I try to authenticate a user, I am getting the following error:

```
{
error: "invalid_request",
error_description: "redirect_uri has wrong domain, check application settings"
}
```

Also, when I am creating application, I don't get any option to specify redirect-url.
Can anybody please help me, as to how should I resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://vk.com/apps?act=manage, select needed app and click Manage. Click Settings on the left sidebar and edit `Authorized redirect URI`, `Base domain` and `Site address` fields (Under the `Open API` title)